# Nginx Is there any default landing page settings to configure when reverse proxy server is down for any reason

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have configured reverse proxy for both (nginx and apache), and it is working as expected, but
when I have changes for my app server and get restarted, during the restart process I am experiencing

*502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)*

when the app server is down.

So I wanted to set a default path with static content(e.g /var/www/example.com/offline.html).
That's why I was looking such option at nginx server but not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use the error_page directive in the server or location.

error_page - Defines the URI that will be shown for the specified errors. A uri value can contain variables.

Example for you (if you have root directive `/var/www/example.com`):

```
server {
    ...
    error_page 502 /offline.html;
    ...
}
```

or:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        ...
        error_page 502 /offline.html;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not worked for me, what will be the full path of the file "offline.html" or where I should place the static html file?

Comment: if you root directive is `root /var/www/example.com;` error page directive must be `error_page 502 /offline.html;` and file must be exist as `/var/www/example.com/offline.html`.

Also check your nginx.conf config, may be error_page directive setting as global